# Converting MYSQL row value into column names

Tags: mysql

I have tables like this:

**job_status_air**

```
status_id  | status
-----------+------------
1          | AIRPORT IN
2          | AIRPORT OUT
```

**job_status_air_pkg**

```
id  | status_id  | package_no
----+------------+------------
1   | 1          | pkg1
2   | 1          | pkg2
3   | 1          | pkg3
4   | 2          | pkg1
```

I am using the below query:

```
select package_no , 
       (case when job_status_air.status = "AIRPORT IN" then job_status_air_pkg.id end) AIRPORTIN, 
       (case when job_status_air.status = "AIRPORT OUT" then job_status_air_pkg.id else 0 end) AIRPORTOUT 
FROM job_status_air_pkg 
LEFT JOIN job_status_air ON (job_status_air.status_id = job_status_air_pkg.status_id) 
WHERE job_status_air.mawb = 'awb1' or hawb = 'awb1'
```

I can't achieve the below result:

```
package_no | AIRPORT IN | AIRPORT OUT
-----------+------------+-------------
 pkg1      |    1       |  4
 pkg2      |    2       |
 pkg3      |    3       |
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Use `alias` that is `...job_status_air_pkg.id end) AS AIRPORTIN, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to apply aggregation and group by

```
select package_no , 
       max(case when job_status_air.status = "AIRPORT IN" then job_status_air_pkg.id end) AIRPORTIN, 
       max(case when job_status_air.status = "AIRPORT OUT" then job_status_air_pkg.id else 0 end) AIRPORTOUT 
FROM job_status_air_pkg 
LEFT JOIN job_status_air ON (job_status_air.status_id = job_status_air_pkg.status_id) 
WHERE job_status_air.mawb = 'awb1' or hawb = 'awb1' 
group by package_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the express reply.
When I use group by, I have having pkg1 for id 4 in a new row

Comment: @ShirleyKuanSF, don't you use max() aggregation

Comment: Oh yeah!! You got my mistake now! You have saved my life! Thanks @fa06 !